# how to create a web app in java(spring framework) with automated service publishing to the ArcGIS server?

Tags: arcmap, java

I am a newbie and my requirement is to create a web application in java. The app depicts the data like success, failures of my orgainsation's ventures at various Geo locations. The geo data is stored as lat/lon in Oracle DB. ArcGIS 10.0 is decided upon to be used.

I have to depict the success, failures on a map. Right now all I know is that we need a service published on the ArcGIS for server which will then needed to be used in my web app's map. Also, I have to automate the process of publishing the service on the ArcGIS for server as and when new data becomes available.

So far I have been browsing ArcGIS site and I have stumbled upon the ArcGIS for Javascript API and checking out few sample codes.

I am quite unsure as how to proceed. Any pointers, tutorials, anything at all towards the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Apache Wicket Java Web Framework

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/07/31/creating-an-agsjws-web-application-with-wicket-framework/

is far easier, efficient and fun !

Francois